# Selenium Scripts are not running on Chrome & Firefox on Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I have `Selenium` webdriver with using `TESTNG` & `Maven`. I can run those test without any issue on `IE`, `Chrome` & `Firefox` from `Eclips`.

When I schedule my test using `Jenkins`, my test runs fine if I am using `IE`, but they are failing on `chrome` & `Firefox`. I am not sure `Selenium Grid`.

Here is the log:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass beforeTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to
discover open pages   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
(36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
information) Command duration or timeout: 60.77 seconds Build info:
version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: , os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',
os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver     at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at Foundation.BrowserFactory.getBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:45)     at
PageObj.LogIn_Page.openApp(LogIn_Page.java:39)  at
Scripts.CreateAppointment.beforeTest(CreateAppointment.java:29)     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
    at
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)    at
org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)  at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)     at
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)    at
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)     at
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)   at
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)    at
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)     at
org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)     at
org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)
```

Functions

```
/*********************************************************
* Function: OpenBrowser()
**********************************************************/
public static void openApp(String browserName, String env) throws Exception{
  driver = BrowserFactory.getBrowser(browserName);
  Log.info("Browser:" + browserName);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get(env);
  Log.info("Env: " + env);
  waitForObj.wait(1);
}
public class BrowserFactory  {
  private static Map<String, WebDriver    drivers = new HashMap<String, WebDriver>();
  /*
  * Factory method for getting browsers
  */
  public static WebDriver getBrowser(String browserName) {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    switch (browserName) {
      case "Firefox":
        driver = drivers.get("Firefox");
        if (driver == null) {
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          drivers.put("Firefox", driver);
        }
        break;
      case "IE":
        driver = drivers.get("IE");
        if (driver == null) {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", SystemUtils.getUserDir() + "\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
          driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
          drivers.put("IE", driver);
        }
      break;
    case "Chrome":
      driver = drivers.get("Chrome");
      if (driver == null) {
          System.out.println(SystemUtils.getUserDir());
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",SystemUtils.getUserDir() + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          drivers.put("Chrome", driver);
      }
      break;
  }
  return driver;
}
```

Comment: Share the code of your `@BeforeClass beforeTest`. Without this it's gonna be hard to help

Comment: @BeforeClass
 // Execute this method before every test.
 public void beforeTest() throws Exception{
  DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml"); 
  //Provide browser name as "IE","FireFox", or "Chrome"
 LogIn_Page.openApp("Chrome","http://ipAddress/html/Shell.html");
  LogIn_Page.validateURL();
  LogIn_Page.login();
  LogIn_Page.NGUE();
  LogIn_Page.validateLogin();
 }

Comment: Please edit your question to add it in a code block instead of adding it in a comment. Also add the `LogIn_Page` code as this is where the error occurs. Especially `LogIn_Page.openapp()`

Comment: @RemcoW added the code to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming you are running your tests locally on jekin server. I suspect m/c on which you are running jekin is not having firefox and chrome browser installed.

Comment: @abhijeetkanade m/c? I am running everything local on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Jenkins on VM? Or the same enviornment that you are running your tests locally? If its running on IE and it runs locally fine on all web browsers and if you are using a VM then it must be down to not have a Firefox and Chrome installed on the VM?

Comment: I am not running Jenkins on VM. Everything is on my local machine. Everything works fine when i run through Eclipse, but from Jenkins i cannot run my scrips on Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: anyone has any input to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, run your Jenkins services in system admin,

1. open to run cmd
2. Enter service and click Okay button
3. A service dialog box open, locate Jenkins services. Go to properties of service
4. Go to logon tab, choose the second option. provide the your admin user not the local server
5. then restart the services.

**This fixed the issue that i was having. Thanks!**